# Customizing sso_redirect.html in wso2 IS 5.0

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to customize the sso_redirect.html page in WSO2 IS 5.0 SP1 found in location IS_HOME\repository\resources\security\sso_redirect.html.

Though any javascript or inline css changes are getting reflected in this page, any reference to images are not honored. for e.g the  tag doesnt fetch the image on the page. Is there any limitation on this front?

Thanks in advance.

Cijoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page could be customized by defining all the resources(style sheet, images, java script, etc..) references  as url instead of relative path. Then those resources may be available at the page loading time.

Comment: thanks Asela. if I have the images under a folder viz IS_HOME\repository\resources\security\images\abc.png What should be the url used?